# htmlToImage Chrome 64 SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Tags: google-chrome, html-to-pdf, wkhtmltoimage

The new Chrome 64 security update seems to have broken the htmlToImage libraries.  None of the styling is correctly calculated and is rendered as if no styling was applied at all.

Does anyone know of a workaround / fix?  Do I need to put my CSS on the server and allow CORS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed this error.

Forked the lib and made a pull request. <strike>Until it gets merged, you can use the forked repo: https://github.com/kmap-io/html-to-image</strike>

by replacing the target of `html-to-image` in your `package.json` with:

```
"html-to-image": "git+https://github.com/kmap-io/html-to-image.git"
```

---

**About the bug**

Chrome is complaining (throws an error) about trying to read a property that does not exist. Firefox also complains, but they only throw a warning, instead of an error. The fix consists of replacing

```
if (sheet.cssRules) {
  ...
```

with

```
if (sheet.hasOwnProperty('cssRules')) {
  ...
```

There is no downside (i.e.: when `cssRules` exists on `sheet` - which is a stylesheet - the script iterates through the rules and adds them to document, as supposed to).

---

**How to patch** (until it gets merged).

For some reason, simply replacing the library's repo with the fork in which I committed the change doesn't work for this package. I asked the lib's author to add instructions on how to build after a pull-request, as they state in the readme pull requests and contributions are welcome. Until then, here's how to apply the fix using `patch-package`:

- add `"prepare": "patch-package"` inside `scripts`, in your project's `package.json`
- `npm i patch-package --save-dev`
- In `node_modules/html-to-image/lib/embedWebFonts.js`, change line 7 from

```js
try {
```

to

```
if (sheet.hasOwnProperty('cssRules')) try {
```

- `npx patch-package html-to-image`

If you have a deployment script that builds your project from scratch, you'll need to apply the patches right before you call `npm run build` (or similar, depending on your stack):

```
git apply --ignore-whitespace patches/*.patch
```

That's about it.

When the fix will be merged, you'll need to run:

```
npx patch-package html-to-image --reverse
```

Comment: I'm getting an error.  Module not found: Can't resolve 'html-to-image'.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @mcottingham I am getting the same error. I wasn't able to find a way to build the module correctly. I asked the module owner to update their readme on how to do it. However, I've found how to apply the change without forking, with `patch-package` module and I'm testing it right now. I'll update my answer after I make it work locally, with all required steps.

Comment: @mcottingham, I updated with all steps I did to make it work for me.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  I has to change the import from `import htmlToImage from 'html-to-image'` to `import * as htmlToImage from 'html-to-image'` and now it works great!